# Nuxt 3 ssr showing two components on page refresh

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

simple useResponsive

```
export default function useResponsive() {
  const isMobile = ref(false);
  const isTabled = ref(false);
  const isDesktop = ref(false);

  onMounted(() => {
    updateWidth();
    window.addEventListener('resize', updateWidth);
  });

  const updateWidth = () => {
    isMobile.value = window.innerWidth <= 640;

    isTabled.value = window.innerWidth > 640 && window.innerWidth <= 1280;

    isDesktop.value = window.innerWidth > 1280;
  };

  return {
    isMobile,
    isTabled,
    isDesktop
  };
}
```

on the page I call like this

```
<div class="tw-py-0 tw-mb-6 xl:tw-py-7 xl:tw-mb-0">
  <LazyMediaMobilePageGallery v-if="isMobile"/>
  <LazyMediaPageGallery v-else/>
</div>


<script lang="ts" setup>
  import useResponsive from '~/composables/useResponsive';

  const { isMobile, isTabled, isDesktop } = useResponsive();
</script>
```

when the page is updated (in mobile mode), the components jump, first the component leaves isDesktop and then it hides and the isMobile component is shown

If SSR: false, then there are no jumps

Comment: Seems legit, you cannot know the viewport of a given div on the server side. If you use it only as SPA, you will only get the page render on client side. But if you use `ssr: true`, you will get some template generated on the server then a hydration which can result into a "jump" of your components. Nothing weird here, this is how it works. You could either have a purely CSS solution or you may wrap the 2 components in `client-only` component but you will lose the static part of your template. No magic sauce here. You can also try to hide the jump with some styling/transition I guess.

Comment: Did you find a fix?