# how to detect user device and load UI accordingly in Nuxt3

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am working on Nuxt3 project.
i want to use different layout for Desktop & Mobile version. on some pages some different components or block depending on device.

> For Example this is default.vue in layouts folder

```
<template>

<!-- Mobile Layout -->
  <div v-if="$isMobile()">
    <TopMenu />
    <NuxtChild />
    <Footer />
  </div>
<!-- Mobile Layout End -->


<!-- Desktop Layout -->
  <a-layout has-sider v-else>
    <a-layout-sider
      :style="{
        background: '#ffffff',
        overflow: 'auto',
        height: '100vh',
        position: 'fixed',
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
      }"
      :class="`ttc-invisible sm:ttc-visible`"
    >
      <MainMenu />
    </a-layout-sider>
    <a-layout :style="{ marginLeft: '202px', background: '#ffffff' }">
      <a-layout-header
        :class="`ttc-container ttc-mx-auto`"
        :style="{
          background: '#ffffff',
          padding: 0,
          position: 'fixed',
          zIndex: 1,
          width: '100%',
          padding: '5px 25px!important',
        }"
      >
        <TopMenu />
      </a-layout-header>
      <a-layout-content
        :style="{
          margin: '24px 16px 0',
          overflow: 'initial',
          padding: '50px 0px 35px 0px',
        }"
      >
        <NuxtChild />
      </a-layout-content>
      <a-layout-footer
        :style="{ padding: '24px 0px 0px 0px', background: '#ffffff' }"
      >
        <Footer />
      </a-layout-footer>
    </a-layout>
  </a-layout>
<!-- Desktop Layout End -->
</template>
```

I am trying to learn to write custom plugins in Nuxt3.
here what i tried to create using mobile-detect library.

> device.js inside plugins folder

```
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app';
import MobileDetect from 'mobile-detect';

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
    let headers = useRequestHeaders()
    const md = new MobileDetect(headers['user-agent'])
    const isMobile = md.phone() !== null || md.mobile() === 'UnknownMobile'
    const isTablet = md.tablet() !== null || md.mobile() === 'UnknownTablet'
    const isDesktop = !isMobile && !isTablet

    return {
        provide: {
            isMobile: () => isMobile,
            isTablet: () => isTablet,
            isDesktop: () => isDesktop
        },
    };
})
```

I am getting this error.

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:571 TypeError: _ctx.$isMobile is not a function
at Proxy._sfc_render (default.vue?import&t=1656113644025:25:16)
at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:896:44)
at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5651:34)
at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:185:25)
at instance.update (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5694:56)
at runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:493:18
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at rerender (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:485:27)
at Object.rerender (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:568:20)
at default.vue?import&t=1656113612067:98:25
```

**update**

> Suddenly Errors are gone and i can check the responses of $isMobile,
> $isDesktop in true and false.
>
> **but when i browse in mobile, first it loads mobile layout and then suddenly it goes back to desktop layout.**
>
> How to resolve this problem

Comment: Pretty much this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72740850/nuxt-3-ssr-showing-two-components-on-page-refresh#comment128483687_72740850

Comment: i followed that question, is there some other solution over here. because i don't want to loose the static part. may be by using state management.

Comment: I don't see how state management can be a solution. Tbh, I don't really see a solution to this anyway. You need to have the viewport size to be able to toggle some content in your template, but for that you need to be on the client. You don't have a window on server. Those 2 things (static template and conditional rendering) are exclusive. You could only achieve this by using a visual hack to hide the jump. You could meanwhile make usage of lazy loading + code splitting until your content is visible tho, but no static conditional rendering feasible here IMO.

Comment: i think, what i need is this module does, but i am afraid it will work with Nuxt3

https://github.com/nuxt-community/device-module

Comment: Whatever the module, I just can't see how such thing would be achievable on the tech side.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I also take "$isMobile is not a function" error on server side.

Comment: @MuzafferKadirYılmaz of course it is not available on the server-side, there is not such thing as a viewport there so media queries are available. You could generate all the viewport sizes ahead of time tho.

Comment: @kissu i could not catch. I couldn't get user agent info from server side so isMobile function doesn't work properly. I am not trying to get device info with viewport.

Comment: @MuzafferKadirYılmaz oh yeah nvm I confused it with the one from Vuetify which is more common. I guess people is referring to this old package: https://github.com/hgoebl/mobile-detect.js that did not received any update in the past years. Anyway you could do it yourself if that library does not work. Also there are quite a few warnings on that repo explaining how User Agent is not a reliable way of doing things which is totally true.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to avoid flicking switching devices. For example i set a background image with css for desktop, but when device is mobile we should not see desktop image

Comment: @MuzafferKadirYılmaz why not use CSS media queries for that exact purpose?

Answer (score 5):

Solved the problem. In plugins/device.js the key was:

```
const md = process.server ? new MobileDetect(headers['user-agent']) : new MobileDetect(navigator.userAgent)
```

After all:

In order to handle mobile/desktop layouts in Nuxt3 (SSR) we can define browser type using userAgent and then define device type with mobile-detect library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mobile-detect)

install `npm i mobile-detect`

yourApp/plugins/device.js:

```js
import {defineNuxtPlugin, useRequestHeaders} from '#app';
import MobileDetect from 'mobile-detect';

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
    let headers = useRequestHeaders()

    const md = process.server ? new MobileDetect(headers['user-agent']) : new MobileDetect(navigator.userAgent)
    const isMobile = md.phone() !== null || md.mobile() === 'UnknownMobile'
    const isTablet = md.tablet() !== null || md.mobile() === 'UnknownTablet'
    const isDesktop = !isMobile && !isTablet

    return {
        provide: {
            isMobile: () => isMobile,
            isTablet: () => isTablet,
            isDesktop: () => isDesktop
        },
    };
})
```

usage:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="$isMobile()" > show on mobile </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Smart solution. Thanks. I was struggling with vuetify's useDisplay() composable in combination with nuxt ssr. The mobile value was alwas true at start if I used vuetify's ssr: true property.

Now I use this native method to detect the device even on ssr :thumbs-up

Comment: can we combine with checking window.innerWidht value? If i check only screen width i get flicker (for example nuxt loads desktop image first then loads mobile image). So I want to combine this to solution is it sensible?

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be done with this too : https://vueuse.org/core/useMediaQuery/

quoting their demo page:

```js
import { useMediaQuery } from '@vueuse/core'

const isLargeScreen = useMediaQuery('(min-width: 1024px)')
const isPreferredDark = useMediaQuery('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)')
```

The var "isLargeScreen" will be true if the browser uses the media query specified. You can do the same for mobile and detect iphones, android too based on that.

vueuse is made to work with nuxt3/vue3 most of their components are pretty straight forward and easy to use. So far im using that and RXJS without noticeable bugs and it works pretty well.